# How to find % change between values in 2 columns in a Pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a Pivot table on a dataset in Excel. I have 2 columns for yearly values and want to insert a new column in the pivot table for % change between them.

I've tried using the "Field Settings" to find percent difference, but it doesn't give the desired result.

[image: The desired result is shown in this picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you don't have gaps between years.

1. Add the amount field to the values section of the pivot table, so that it is there twice.
2. Right-Click one of the values in the newly added
3. Choose `Show Values As` -> `% Of ...` ->
4. `Base Field` should be: Year and `Base Item` should be: (previous)
5. Rename column to % Difference
6. It will show for every year, so hide the column for years that you don't want it

Answer (score 1):

Not too hard, when you have your pivot table:

- Select any cell
- Go to Excel Ribbon > PivotTable Analyse > Fields, Items & Sets > Calculated Field
- Give a title, e.g.: `% Difference` and add a formula:

  ```
  = ('2018-19'-'2017-18' )/'2017-18'
  ```
- Confirm and once confirmed, change the datatype of this field to percentage

[image]

***Note***, things might be named a little different in your Excel since I'm using a Dutch Excel 2019 version.

Comment: I tried that but '2018-19' and '2017-18' are not available as "Fields" in the "Calculated Field" dialog box. The field that they belong to is called "Year". Upon typing the formula you suggested, I got an error "There's a problem with this formula..". Also, there are some empty fields (when a value for a year doesn't exist) which I am wary that they would give division error.

Comment: @themaverick, that's because when you add the formula, you have to actively click the fieldnames. You have to build the query yourself. I added the formula to demonstrate how it kind of should look when you have to do it. I think empty fields will be treated as 0